# What does the .corr() method do in Pandas and how does it relate it to the heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I was doing a tutorial about EDA using the jupyter gallery and found this code confusing:-

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
c = df.corr()
sns.heatmap(c,cmap="BrBG", annot=True)
```

Here, the dataframe is defined as df. However, I don't get the purpose of df.corr() and how does it relate to heatmap. I tried searching df.corr() and found out that it's used to perform pairwise operations.

Here's the link to jupyter gallery: https://colab.research.google.com/github/Tanu-N-Prabhu/Python/blob/master/Exploratory_data_Analysis.ipynb#scrollTo=dAnd4DSyeHDb

Would appreciate clarity on my issues.

Comment: the default method is `'pearson'` so for all pairwise column combinations it calculates [`np.corrcoeff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html). You can see exactly what functions it uses for the different methods in [pandas.core.nanops](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/nanops.py#L1331-L1358)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

`df.corr()` calculates the correlation matrix whose elements range is `[-1, 1]`, by default it uses Pearson Correlation coefficient. `sns.heatmap` is just a way to display using colors how strong the correlations are, where the color green in this case suggest a positive correlation close to `1`.

It's just a way to see the correlations with colors instead of a number so the user can identify which variables are more correlated.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Are you able to explain it in layman terms? I just started learning Linear Algebra so matrix is a relatively new topic for me. What I understood from your answer is that it tells you the correlation between two variables. Also, are you able to tell me why is it important in Explanatory Data Analysis?

Comment: This is beyond the initial question but in general, whenever you have a correlation close to 1 or -1 between variable `X` and variable `Y` it means `Y` can be explained by a linear equation using `X` as a variable, for example: `Y = A X + B`, the closest to 1 or -1, the more precise this equation is.

Answer (score 0):

.corr() finds the correlation between every column(variable) in the dataframe with one another, it returns a 2D-Datamatrix.

`corr = df.corr()`   //df is my dataframe

The data values are represented as colors in the heatmap. The goal of the heatmap is to provide a colored visual summary of information.

`plt.figure(figsize= (20,22))
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True)
plt.show()`